# file_get_contents method return some value with strange symbols while calling a php API. Unable to view in browser

Tags: php, api, file, pdf

Getting Strange response from file_get_contents Method in php

```
$binaryfile = file_get_contents('https://xyz.abc.ee/api/file.php?hash='.$final_hash_std_cert.'&action=getFile&name='.$cert, false, stream_context_create($stream_opts));
echo $binaryfile;
```

on ajax side i'm doing this :

```
productCert = $(this).attr('data-cert');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // use $_POST method to submit data
    url: my_ajaxurl, // where to submit the data
    data: {
        action     : 'load_cert_action',
        cert_url : productCert, // PHP: $_POST['first_name']
    },
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data); // here i'm getting strange output
        //window.location.assign(data);
        // var pdfWindow = window.open("");
        // pdfWindow.document.write(data)
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown); // error
    }
});
```

Getting this response in console :

> %PDF-1.5 %���� 5 0 obj <>stream
>   H���yTSw�oɞ����c [���5,   ��
>   �BHBK!aP�V�X��=u����:X��K�è���Z\;v^�����N�����߽��~��w��.M�h�a

this is just first four five lines. this is very large string of strange charters. I think issue with some UTF format. Not so sure. Help me please.

Comment: That's not strange. What are you actually trying to achieve? I doubt outputting the source of a PDF file is what you're after.

Comment: just want to show the pdf file in a new tab

Comment: Then you need to open the link in a new tab (would a button / anchor link not do? AJAX might not be required here?) and make sure the Content-Type header in the PHP response is correct for a PDF (application/pdf , perhaps?)

Comment: using this header('Content-type: application/pdf') before ech. so what you suggestme to do?

Comment: how to open it in new tab without ajax ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript might help. Unsure.

Comment: Thanks but they are playing with base64 in answers :(

Comment: So? Is there something stopping you from using Base64?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192670/discussion-between-danish-farhaj-and-jonnix).