# Chrome window.open shows Failed - Network error

Tags: google-chrome

I am using window.open to open a popup and display a result (PDF)
this is working fine with IE/fire fox
and the same used to work fine with chrome until not so long ago.

[here is a live example, codepen editor seems to work better then stack](https://codepen.io/01081980/pen/rNBWJYw)

This is what I see in chrome:
[image: Chrome]

This is the code:

```js
function openWindow(winUrl,winName,winParams)
 {
  var win = window.open(winUrl, winName, winParams);
  win.focus();
 }
  
function showInspection(inspectionId){
     alert('inspectionId:' + inspectionId);
     openWindow('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf','fullscreen=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=auto,menubar=yes,location=0,status=1');
   }
```

```html
<a download target="_blank" href="javascript:showInspection('1')">
<img title="download1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bremen/32/phone.png"/>
</a>
<a download target="_blank" href="javascript:showInspection('2')">
<img title="download2" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bremen/32/phone.png"/>
</a>
<a download target="_blank" href="javascript:showInspection('3')">
<img title="download3" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bremen/32/phone.png"/>
</a>
```

I am not sure why but this code is working fine on eclipse, but not on stackoverflow editor - although chrome show the same symptoms.

**UPDATE**

I added a codepan that shows the issue

[here is a live example](https://codepen.io/01081980/pen/rNBWJYw)

I updated chrome to Version 76.0.3809.87 (Official Build) (32-bit)
now it will not show the network error just open a blank window with "about:blank" in the URL

[image: just open a blank window with "about:blank" in the URL]

Comment: why you don't try `window.open("data:application/pdf," + "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"); ` like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Updated [codepen example](https://s.codepen.io/peterschussheim/debug/dybOmpx/RBAOJXLdOXjr), opens in 'debug' mode to demonstrate the code running in a more realistic envirnment than normal codepen editor.  If you want to edit or see the code, [this link](https://codepen.io/peterschussheim/pen/dybOmpx) opens the editor.

Snippet added below with modifications for quick reference (note this **will not work in StackSnippets**):

```js
function openWindow(winUrl, winName, winParams) {
  var win = window.open(winUrl, winName, winParams);
  // win.focus();
}

function showInspection(inspectionId) {
  alert("inspectionId:" + inspectionId);
  openWindow(
    "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf",
    "fullscreen=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=auto,menubar=yes,location=0,status=1"
  );
}

const phoneIcon = document.getElementById('phone')
phoneIcon.addEventListener('click', showInspection)
```

```html
<a download target="_blank" id="phone">
  <img title="download1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bremen/32/phone.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: I put your code in a new codepen because link you added is not working, there is some progress, i see the PDF URL is correct in chrome, but it will not show the content.


https://codepen.io/01081980/pen/mdbOLaL

Comment: @user648026, I just confirmed the [codepen link](https://s.codepen.io/peterschussheim/debug/dybOmpx/nqAwvWwNQzPr) from my answer works and opens a new tab with the PDF. Perhaps try again?

Comment: this link is working in chrome, but i am unable to see the codepen code, all i see is the icon, can you share the link again?

Comment: i thought it was working correctly but its not, its opening the pdf, but still showing download failed network error.,....

Comment: @user648026 please check out this [screen recording](http://g.recordit.co/2CqXAj0Suz.gif) I made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198264/discussion-between-user648026-and-peter).