# SAPUI5 servlet call to a pdf

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, sapui5, pentaho

I have a SAPUI js controller that will call a servlet to display a pdf file. However, the url call returns a response which I believe is a pdf xstring format. Basically if i open the url directly it will just display the pdf, but since i am calling the servlet, there is no window opened.

Following is my call.

```
            $.ajax({
                url : 'http://localhost/pentaho',
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                success : function(data) {

                },
                error : function(data){
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            });
```

I am using GET as i would need to pass some parameters to the servlet but I just require the pdf to be displayed. The ajax call is successfull with the variable (data) filled with which I believe the xstring binary pdf.

Question : 1. Can i call the servlet url and let the pdf open in another window without a response ?
           2. How do i format the response string to display as pdf in sapui5 if above is not possible.

The data stream looks like this.

%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
21422 0 obj
<>stream
hÞœ›Q,Çq¥ÿÊ

Hope you can help shed some light into the matter.

Thanks.
Anand

Comment: You can follow the guide https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PDFViewer%23controlProperties
Also for embedded from data variable you can use "data:application/pdf," + encodeURI(pdfString)
Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript

Comment: You say that if you open the URL directly it will just display the pdf. Then why don't you just open the URL in a new tab via JavaScript? `window.open("http://localhost/pentaho")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both suggestion works and gave me some hints to progress. Finally went with the following.

Set the source with the URL options as parameters

```
                       var source = "/pentaho?P_WERKS="+oClient;
                        var _pdfurl = source;
                            this.oPDFViewer = new sap.m.PDFViewer();
                            this.oPDFViewer.setSource(_pdfurl);
                            this.oPDFViewer.open();
```

Thanks.
Anand