# How to display a pdf file from the buffer of a mime type application/pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, dom, amazon-ses

I am trying to write an email client that reads email files that have been sent to an S3 bucket via AWS SES and displays those email files in a browser like other email clients do.  One of the tasks that I am grappling with is how to display the attachments which I get in the form of a buffer.  For example, for a pdf attachment, I get a data buffer of contentType "application/pdf". Is there a way to embed this data stream into a HTML field such that it shows up as a properly formatted pdf document?

here is screen shot of what I have at the client page level:
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the amazon part, but if the Browser has a PDF reader you could just create a link like `<a href='pdflocation.pdf'>View PDF</a>`. If you want to view it in the same page you could use an `<frame src='pdflocation.pdf#Fit'></iframe>`, but that won't work on Chrome mobile, so what's the point.

Comment: thanks @StackSlave, but there is no "pdflocation"...the buffer is generated "on the fly" from the eml file using Mailparser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailparser).  I never actually have a pdf file per se -- only its representation as this data buffer extracted from the larger eml file.

Comment: If it's a blob then `document.querySelector('a').href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`. Note that will just get the first `<a></a>` on the page. You may want to use a different getter.

Comment: ps., at this point I am NOT necessarily looking for a solution that will also work on a mobile platform.  For now I am focusing only on a web/html client.

Comment: @StackSlave Thanks, but it is not a blob and I don't know how to turn it into a blob. :(

Comment: I am thinking that this might be relevant to answering my question.  Any thoughts from out there?     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: this is also relevant:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript

Comment: ???? It looks like it could be an ArrayBufffer? Try `document.querySelector('a').href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([globalVal.attachments[0]], {type:'application/pdf'}));` or some variation. Good luck!