# convert bytes to downloadable pdf javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, blob

I am sending a post request with file name ("123.pdf") and getting a response like

```
%âãÏÓ
4 0 obj
<</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 418/Filter/DCTDecode/Type/XObject/Width 502/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 51748>>stream
[...]
Rœ¥»    NRÜ±ŠåîþxVúö{»0¼ó¹’FûD£,NIÀlQ¸½8½z/ƒ´]½Ö—b`™ÓËfó¤|®AÆˆê×ƒ´/Ý%Î©bgš4òÕ¼çL.IÆ€êMòææ<¹¹Š6ÿ
ü/iyowk`ðÏo*ÊŒ·Täd3Œ×V(”Ü·§)n-$…Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@1ÝcRÎÁTrI8€#†îÞåI‚xå©Ãcò¥0<±4eó»†sô¢ÌvcÞDw;QÜœ
c\DŠŽò¢«–q=úÐ+1dš8P¼²*
```

How can I convert this to downloadable pdf in javascript react ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening PDF String in new window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript)

Comment: No this not working.